# How to run docky in 3d mode?

Tags: docky

I want to use docky but, he uses 2d mode :( How to run in 3D?

UPD: I have got this black field... bottom left.

This is emulated 3d?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the anchor icon to bring up the preferences window, click on the dock you want to configure, then tick the '3D Background' box. This option is only available if the dock is on the bottom side of the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> This is emulated 3d?

Insofar as somebody doesn't come round your house and build a real model "dock" for you, nor will you need anaglyph or polarizing glasses, yes.

The "3D background" is just an effect. An illusion at perspective. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the docky icon (the anchor)
2. Click Settings
3. Select "3d background" checkbox in the 'Docks' tab.